# How to write the tree diagram for the following ambiguous sentence: "The design has large squares and circles."?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is the tree diagram for the following ambiguous sentence?

> The design has large squares and circles.

Comment: Why do you think it's ambiguous? I suppose "circles" could be a verb, but that's a stretch.

Comment: @user888379 Because it's not clear whether the adjective "large" modifies just the noun "squares," or whether it modifies the entire phrase "squares and circles."

Comment: @QuackE.Duck That's true, and less exotic than my notion of a design that circles.

Comment: @user888379 I hadn't even thought of that one! So it's *triply* ambiguous...

Comment: I'd diagram according to the interpretation I hear: large (squares and circles). Can't be marked wrong for having other interpretations, too.

Comment: @user888379 Doesn't the verb "circles" need an object? (There are some exceptions, such as omitting the object when an airplane circles.)

Comment: @Barmar Or maybe an adverb ("circle back"). And I'm definitely not attached to the  reading "a design that circles".